# How to check if a given value is a number or not in Freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

In freemarker how do I find out if a particular value is a number or not. Is there any specific method to check if a given value is a number or not in freemarker?

```
<#if (link_data.canonical)!?matches(".*/sites/.*") && (pageData.ar.gP)?has_content >
    <#if (pageData.ar.gP)?is_number >
        <link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/${(pageData.ar.gP)!}" />
    <#else>
        <link rel="ar" href="https://plus.google.com/+${(pageData.ar.gP)!}" />
    </#if>
</#if>
```

The above code does not work for me.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Do you want to know if a String value contains a number or whether a particular model element holds something that subclasses `java.lang.Number`?

Comment: if "id" is a variable in freemarker , I want to know if id is a number   or not.Can I use something like id?is_number

Answer (score 10):

Yeah, Freemarker has some built-ins for that.  You can do `id?is_number` or `?is_string` or `?is_boolean`, etc.

source: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_isType

Comment: Can you also add the code where pageData.ar.gP (or its container) is defined?

Comment: What about `is_float` or `is_integer`?

Answer (score 0):

Try id?is_number?c or ?is_string?c or ?is_boolean?c

just add ?c at the end

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the number is Integer with this function:

```
<#assign test = 2>
${isInteger(test)?c}
<#function isInteger number>
<#return number?floor == number>
</#function>
```

returns true